# How to set a condition/restriction to an Object Property in Protege?

Tags: owl, protege

I have established various relationships between individuals:

[image]

Process 1 sets the value of individual A to true.
Process 2 then initiates B.

How can I model the ontology so that the object property initiates is only executed when the value of B is true?

Comment: that's impossible for explicit property assertions given that reasoning in OWL is monotonic - what you can try to do is to infer such a second relation via a value restriction or maybe just by using SWRL.